# I am exporting Form component into body component but it gives this error

Tags: reactjs

[image]

import React from 'react'
import Form from './components/formcomponent';

```
const Body = () =>{
    return (
        <div className="body">
            <h1 className="heading">Welcome User</h1>
            <Form />
        </div>
    )
}
```

export default Body

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Form extends Component{
    render(){
        return <h1>Hello Mujahid</h1>
    }
}

export default Form
```

Comment: Click the given image

Comment: Is the file containing the Form component named `formcomponent`? Is it in the same folder as body?

Comment: yes the name of the file is formcomponent.js and its in the component folder where body component file named body.js is present

Comment: In that case your import ought to be `import Form from './formcomponent.js'`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the path for formcomponent once again.

If the file exists in the same floder the path should be :-

`import Form from './formcomponent.js'`